# Insert records in oracle database using c# odbc

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, odbc

I am messing around in C# trying to understand how to insert records into a database using C# ODBC. I have learned how to read in records to a `DGV`, but now I am getting stuck on inserting. 
The quick overview of what my code is doing, its reading in 20 rows from a table into a `DGV`, then after that it should insert the same rows into a different table.

I am using VS 2012 and SQL Developer (Oracle).

Here is the code in my Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 20; rows++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); // adding needed amount of rows

            for (int cols = 0; cols < 13; cols++)
            {
                this.dataGridView1[cols, rows].Value = getNumberOfThreads(rows, cols);
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.AppendLine("insert into chsarp_test_table");
        sql.AppendLine("SELECT *");
        sql.AppendLine("FROM legal_transactions");
        sql.AppendLine("WHERE rownum between 1 and 25");

        //using (DataTable dt = Database.GetData(sql.ToString()))
        //    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        //  Database dt = new Database.SetData(sql.ToString());
        Database.SetData(sql.ToString());
    }

    public static string getNumberOfThreads(int i, int j)
    {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendLine("SELECT *");
        sql.AppendLine("FROM legal_transactions");
        sql.AppendLine("WHERE rownum between 1 and 25");

        using (DataTable dt = Database.GetData(sql.ToString()))
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                return dt.Rows[i][j].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "null" : dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

        return "null";
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code from my Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Odbc; //used for the ODBC stuff
using System.Data; // Used for public static datatable
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
class Database
{

    private const string connOdbc = "dsn=atlas32;uid=NAME;pwd=XXXX";
    private const string cnnOLE = "provider =XXXX;User ID = NAME;password = XXXX; Data Source = XXX Properties=;Persist Security Info=False";

    public static DataTable GetData(string Sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection cnn = GetConnection();
            using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(Sql, cnn))
            {
                da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            CloseConnection(cnn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Queries.LogErrors(ex.Message, Sql);
            MessageBox.Show("Error 1");

        }
        return dt;
    }

    public static void SetData(string sql)
    {

        try
        {
            OdbcConnection cnn = GetConnection();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            CloseConnection(cnn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Queries.LogErrors(ex.Message, sql);
            MessageBox.Show("Error 2");
        }

    }

    private static OdbcConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection cnn = new OdbcConnection() { ConnectionString = connOdbc };
            cnn.Open();
            return cnn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void CloseConnection(OdbcConnection Connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Connection.Close();
                Connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
        }
        Connection = null;
    }

}

}
```

I tried to step through the code and it goes down in the `SetData` `Method` on the `ExecuteNonQuery`. I tried to look into this but couldnt mind any information that helped me, any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Well I get the message box stating "Error 2" because its going down in the SetData Method. Would it be more beneficial to remove the catch and see what I would normally get?

Comment: Before your Error 2 messagebox, you catch an exception. What does the Message property contain?

Comment: Ah I have that commented out, let me run it again and display that in the Message Box.

Comment: Sigh, how can I give you rep for answering my incredibly silly mistake. Thank you for pointing out the exception, I apparently forgot to add the schema (even though its mine and I figured I didnt need to add it). It works now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Schema on the table I was inserting on. found this out with the help of @stuartd in the comment section of the question.